# Why does this JavaScript nonsense alert "fail"?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I realize that this is intended as a joke, but someone posted this and it alerts "fail" in the browser, what is going on that makes this happen?

```
alert((![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]);
```

Comment: Someone posted it on Facebook, I don't know where it comes from otherwise

Comment: Anyway, the main "trick" to this is that `(![]+[])` results in a string - `"false"` - which is then indexed as `"false"[+[]]` -> `"false"[0]"` -> `"f"`, etc

Comment: And `([]+[][[]])` results in the string `undefined`. The two strings provide all you need to get `f`, `a`, `i`, and `l` with appropriate indexing.

Comment: I found it interesting enough on a serious level I must say, gives you good insight into programming possibilities

Comment: I don't think this is not a serious question, but I did not realize it was answered before (thank you user2864740), closing due to duplicate...

Comment: *"what is going on that makes this happen"* type conversion ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good blog post about this topic: http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html

You basically create strings ("false","undefined" and others) and again use addition of true's to get the indexes.

For example the first letter (f):
`(![]+[])[+[]]`
You use `![]` to get false, and add `[]` to convert it into a string. The content within the parenthesis is now "false". You then access it like an array, and ´+[]` converts to 0 (false as a number).

Comment: Wow, the additions of `true` basically blew my mind. I was wondering how this kind of indexing worked… +1

Comment: @asimes Yeah, it's a pretty fun way of writing code that nobody understands. I would read through the whole article if you haven't already

Comment: In process of, thanks